# Best way to create a list with hidden columns with Data pulling from InfoPath form

Tags: list, infopath, list-view, lookup-column, column

So I have been working on this for a little bit here is what I am trying to accomplish:

Using OOTB SharePoint 2010 Functionality I want to create an HR Referral System. Basically an InfoPath Form will populate a list where the user can then see the status of their referral (hired, contacted, etc). I also want to have the HR team to be able to write their comments in an additional column and what they are actually doing about the referral, which then needs to be hidden from the normal user.

I am able to create the Infopath form, populate the list, and restrict the user ability to see additional columns and create new views. However since it is an Infopath SharePoint List form the HR users are unable to then access the columns to leave their feedback. I have tried working with a 2nd list and pulling the information of the user and then having it loop back to the original list, but it is getting messy.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Please let me know if I need to clarify. Gratzi